# Get the language currently set for listings

Tags: listings, variable

How can I get the language currently set for the listings (aka `lstlistings`) package, e.g. via `\lstset{language=Python,basicstyle=\color{blue},backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}}`?

---

Details:

I want to use the value in my own command that also puts some `lstinline` text into the index, under the right language.

I tried variables like `\language`, `\lst.language`, ... But they do not contain the value.

Hence I introduced a new variable via e.g. `\newcommand{\lstLanguage}{Python}` in each chapter, and used `\lstset{language=\lstLanguage,basicstyle=\color{blue},backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}}` instead. But that causes the error

> ​ ! Package Listings Error: language Python undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is stored in `\lst@language`. The following minimal example shows how to get the currently set listings language from LaTeX and yields `tex python`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\getlang}{\lst@language}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=tex}



\getlang

\lstset{language=Python,basicstyle=\color{blue},backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray}}


\getlang


\end{document}
```